# The principal directions bissect the asymptotic directions

Tags: differential-geometry, conic-sections, surfaces, vector-fields, curvature

I was trying to prove that:

> At a hyperbolic point, the principal directions bissect the asymptotic directions.

Well, I tried to use the Euler's formula:

Being $dN_p$ with eigenvalues $k_1,k_2$, eigeinvectors $e_1,e_2$, take $v$ one asymptotic direction. So, write $v=\cos\theta e_1+\sin \theta e_2$, $\theta $ the angle from $e_1$. We have:

$$II_p(v)=0\iff\\
0=\cos^2\theta k_1+\sin^2 \theta k_2\iff\\
\sin^2 \theta=\dfrac{-k_1}{k_2-k_1};\cos^2\theta=\dfrac{k_2}{k_2-k_1}.$$

To get bissection, I thought that I should obtain $\sin^2 \theta=\cos^2\theta$. I cannot finish.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Who's bisecting whom? Read the statement carefully and say what it means.

Comment: In fact, I didn't quite understand who bisects whom, I thought it means bisecting the angle, ie making 45º angles with the axes. Many thanks!

Comment: It's saying that if you draw the two asymptotic lines, then the angle(s) between them are bisected by the principal lines.

Comment: Right, but the principal lines are theaxes, are not? Thank you. I was reading also you text about DGeometry

Comment: Oh, maybe they are not the axes... But just ortonormals... Are not? But in this case... How can I relate the eigenvalues with the direction of eigenvectors...?

Comment: Yes, when you write down Euler's formula, the principal directions are the axes (i.e., $\theta = 0,\pi/2$). So what are the asymptotic directions?

Comment: I imagine $\theta=\pi/4,3\pi/4$, but in this case $|\sin\theta|=|\cos\theta|$, which is not by sure from the last line of calculus on post... Is the line wrong? Thanks

Comment: You're not processing what I've told you. You keep saying the same thing you started with, which is incorrect. Start over.

Comment: Ohh.... Now I see. I saw an image in a site and now I see. I am so sorry. In fact I was misplacing who bissects whom. $\theta$ can be any angle, but I may have $\pi-\theta$ also a asymtotic direction... right ?And this matches, once I have $\sin^2(\pi-\theta)=\sin^2\theta$ and $\cos^2(\pi-\theta)=\cos^2\theta$. Is it?

Comment: If it's OK for you, you could post some comments as an answer, so I could accept as a way to thank. Well, sorry for my errors and thank you, Mr Shifrin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**HINT**: Solve your equation
$$0 = k_1\cos^2\theta + k_2\sin^2\theta$$
for $\theta$.